# What attributes identify a "cheese build" in SC2?

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What exactly is a “cheese” in Starcraft 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1724/what-exactly-is-a-cheese-in-starcraft-2)

What is the definition of a "cheese build", specifically with reference to standard SC2 builds? Where did the term "cheese build" originate?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1724/what-exactly-is-a-cheese-in-starcraft-2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A cheese build is any build that is generally **unstable** in the long-run, but is used to **exploit** a single **weakness**.

The term "cheese build" is closely related to the term "[cheesy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cheesy)".

> 3 . (informal) of poor quality through
>   being overdramatic, excessively 
>   emotional  or clichéd, trite,
>   contrived, shoddy
>
> 4 . (informal) of a solution to a problem,
>   inelegant, showing no skill (see brute
>   force method)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://sc2gg.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=5061)'s a good guide on the term

> Of all the nastiest most hateful strategies in Starcraft, the most annoying ones are  basically any form of cheese. It's nasty, gooey, disgusting, evil, and annoying.
>   However, a lot of people have some misconceptions about cheese.
>   First of all, here's my definition of cheese:
>
> A strategy that follows these conditions:
>
> - Takes the initiative
> - Is hard to scout
> - Designed to win the game with the least amount of effort.
> - Leaves the cheeser at a severe disadvantage if the strategy fails to do sufficient damage.

[Read more...](http://sc2gg.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=5061)

Comment: Of the four conditions listed above, I would apply three of them to the definition for a "great winning strategy".