# Is it worth to play random?

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [As a bronze league hopeful, is it better to focus on one race or should I keep playing as random?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9373/as-a-bronze-league-hopeful-is-it-better-to-focus-on-one-race-or-should-i-keep-pl)

Usually, I play one race. After being promoted to 1 more higher league I've tried to play random... Off course, I began to lose a lot... definitely, other races require other BO, other micro, other strategy, other skills.

What I see beneficial of playing random is:

1. Your opponent doesn't know your race
   in the beginning and can't choose
   good BO from the very beginning, he
   needs to scout earlier (hart
   economy) or start from 'common' BO
   that can't be too scary for you
   usually as it could be if he plays
   SPECIFICALLY against your race.
2. Playing (and winning) random you will get almost twice more achievements: for example for 100 win as terran you will get only 4 "Solo Terran 10, 25, 50, 100" achievements. While playing random you will receive 4 "Solo Random 10, 25, 50, 100" and 6 more: "Solo Terran 10, 25", "Solo Zerg 10, 25", "Solo Protoss 10, 25" (some variations could happen though).
3. You practice different races, so your knowledge about their strong/weak sides could be better then if you play 1 race only.

As a drawback I could say that you won't play your 1 race as good if you will play other races too.

What do you think about? Does other races knowledge value is bigger then better knowledge of your "own" race?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I feel like this has been asked before...

Comment: Found it: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9373/as-a-bronze-league-hopeful-is-it-better-to-focus-on-one-race-or-should-i-keep-pl

Comment: and tangentially related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7091/getting-better-playing-other-races

Comment: Duplicate: [As a bronze league hopeful, is it better to focus on one race or should I keep playing as random?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9373/as-a-bronze-league-hopeful-is-it-better-to-focus-on-one-race-or-should-i-keep-pl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer maybe a little off pudding to playing random...

...but the big benefit in trying other races for me is to find their weaknesses and strengths.  Know your enemy.  If I'm having a hard time beating an aggressive Terran player while playing Zerg, I might opt to play as an aggressive Terran for so many games.  I'll get to see how other Zerg players face an aggressive Terran.  I'll experience Terran's weak strategy points. I'll know their exact timings.

Answer (score 0):

As with other games, if you are interested in a high level of play, **focus**. In an RPG if you want a level 70 archer, you need to focus on archer-ish things. If you want a well-rounded character, it may be more fun, but you will level up much slower.

In SC2, if you go random, you will experience more diverse play, which may be more fun. For me this is the case.

So I'll play the cliché "it's your preference" card, and say that if your desire is to play at a high level, then only play random if you want to learn just enough about the other races to BEAT THEM better.

Basically, if you like random, do it. If you feel that it's holding you back, then stop. If you are torn between this, it's only something you can answer for yourself.