# Can you find a replay that defends against a well executed proxy rush on Blistering Sands?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-protoss

See this [related question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9156/how-to-counter-a-proxy-zealot-rush-on-blistering-sands/9165#9165). Can you find/post a replay of a **well executed** proxy rush that is successfully defended against? (Not a counter-rush that succeeds, that requires pre-comitting to a rush. I mean a more durable strategy that successfully scouts and defends against this kind of rush).

Note the specific location I prefer for the proxy setup is around the gold that is near the opponents base, outside of usual scouting area and watch tower.

Edit - sorry, I wasn't specific enough. I marked my favorite spot for proxying on this map - this is a rarely scouted place. Also, recently I usually don't send a probe right on the start, but rather build my 2nd pylon there, then warp 3 gateways.

[image]

Comment: I wonder in which leagues it might work... by that time the enemy will have a scout in your base and wonder what you are doing. Every at least decent player will scout for proxys in every possible location and immedatly build a lot of defense if he doesn't see a warpgate in your base around 13 food or if he sees you cutting workers.

Comment: @dbemerlin - I'm 1st rank in Silver league for some time now with a good win percentage. I imagine when I get reranked that I'll be in Gold or hopefully Platinum soon. It works because by the time the enemy realizes what's happening, it's often too late (I can use the back door, so guarding the front entrance isn't good enough). In one game my opponent just scouted the back door when my zealots were munching on it - but it was too late for him to build defenses. I want to see a good replay of this strategy beaten.

Comment: You propably won't, because on blistering sands the scouting distance is too short, so it's too dangerous to proxy against any good players. It might work in bronze, silver and maybe even gold, but higher than that every player knows how to scout and detect your proxy before it can do any damage. This is why most good players don't even try it. The players you beat with that are the players you would kill easily anyways.

Answer (score 6):

[This PvZ replay](http://www.sc2replayed.com/replays/89116-1v1-protoss-zerg-blistering-sands) has the folllowing:

- Proxy in the exact location you describe, behind 2 gateways.
- Successful scout with a Drone, no gateways or cores so immediately looks for the proxy.
  He does this in both Tzenes spot (in vision of his drone) and your spot.
- Successful scout with an Overlord, nothing in Tzenes spot nor gateways after the Drone leaves.
- The Zealots, Stalkers and Proxy being countered by Zerglings and Roaches.
- This is followed by an expand by Zerg and a series of pushes by both players.

Although Zerg didn't win in the end, I consider he countered the Proxy fine and messed up later.

If you want, just ask and we can try to figure out what went wrong later...

[See the end of this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9103/when-not-to-zealot-rush/9109#9109) on how Terran (MM) and Protoss (2gate) counter with the same scouting.

Comment: The Drone and Overlord both cover the [Sweet Spot Circle](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9156/how-to-counter-a-proxy-zealot-rush-on-blistering-sands/9165#9165). What do you mean?

Comment: Actually, this is not the location that I meant :) It is indeed to easy to scout for it. See updated question. Also, I usually now build my 2nd pylon in that spot, warp 3 gateways, and build up 4-5 zealots before attacking through the backdoor. It is this kind of strategy that I want to see defeated.

Comment: @ripper234: That place is rare and it would be hard to find a replay for it as it doesn't have a name, it would require one to create a replay for that. And if you perform this several times yourself I guess you will have a replay soon by someone who manages to counter it... The location you pointed out is weak, the Probe passes over the natural entrance where your Zealots could run, the Xal'Naga Tower covers the path between both entrances. He can see down the ledge. So it wouldn't be hard to figure out with his Drone and army to figure out where your units are coming from.

Comment: Besides that, your opponent will have map advantage as they have higher ground when attacking you...

Comment: It might be better to place a proxy pylon at both the two middle blue bases (warp units to the other one later, perhaps for taking out a gold expo) so the distance to your base and the enemy is near equal and you have excellent map control. But now I'm just Theory-Crafting, one would have to try it a few times...

Comment: @TomWij - I have been executing this strategy, and only lost to an occasional counter rush, never to an actual defense. By the time my opponent spots this then it is usually too late - but I will be happy to be proven wrong about this, if any (European) player is up for it. Of course, it wouldn't actually be a fair chance because he would know my strategy beforehand ... so never mind.

Comment: A counter rush would indeed be the way to go if your Pylon isn't in the usual locations, as the added distance you have to travel to get your Zealots into his base (and to stop his units) allows him to do the counter attack and win with it. My Theory-crafting proposal might counter this as you could distribute your units around the middle and disallow your opponent to get past you... But indeed, you might still go up now but I think you might eventually meet such counter. Yes, such replay would have to be forced as in acting that you're not there and acting like figuring out the army source.